# Move solution from VS2010 to VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, migration

How can I move a solution from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open old solution in Visual Studio 2017. There will be a help utility that will back up our old project, and create reports about updates where you will find useful info about the migration.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this tutorial.[Microsft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

It Helps you troubleshoot your problems if you run into any also it tells you the compatibility of files  and whether you can or cant open the files.

> If you try to open a project that isn't supported in Visual Studio
>   2017 or Visual Studio 2015 and for which the associated version of
>   Visual Studio isn't installed, a message that the project type isn't
>   supported might appear and the project type might be listed in the
>   Review Project and Solution Changes dialog box under Unsupported
>   projects. To resolve this issue, open the programs and features page
>   in the Windows Control Panel, select Visual Studio, and then choose
>   Change, Repair. Then you can install the missing version.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects) is Microsoft official page on migration with VS 2017.

> According to this topic some project types are not supported VS17 therefore can't be migrated.

For that you have to install a [workload](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-vs) to the Visual Studio to make compatible with migration.

- You can run solution to any version of Visual Studio but can't use the features in lower version that are supported in higher version.
- The topic will also give you breakdowns of the compatibility between the particular types of files in different versions Visual Studio.
- You can create, transfer and modify the projects and files of different versions.